# Center three DIVs on center DIV

Tags: html, css

High.  I have three DIVs in a footer.  A DIV of text, a vertical line, and another DIV of text.  I want the center line to always be in the center of the page, even though the two text divs could be of different lengths.

```
<footer id="center-footer" class="clearfix">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="legalese alpha">
        <p>Follow Along on  <a href="#">Instagram</a> and <a href="#">Pinterest</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-divider"></div>
    <div class="legalese alpha">
        <p>See my new online course</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I gave the footer-divider class a single border to make it a center dividing line.  How can I make the center line always be in the center and the text DIVs extending out from there.

I'v tried making the center-footer footer text-align:center, and making the two divs text-align right and left, but it simply centers the whole section.

Thanks.

Comment: OK.  I think I have a solution.  I set the class .wrapper to position:relative and each of the three child elements to position:absolute and then set the first two divs to right:50% and the last div to left:50%  Seems to work.

Comment: You should post CSS too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are only using the middle div as a divider, you technically only need two divs instead of 3.  Why not make each side 50% and place a border in the middle like the following example:

```css
div{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

footer div:first-child{
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

footer div:last-child{
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div>left side</div>
  <div>right side</div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle with an answer: http://jsfiddle.net/stackolee/f2ek7c4k/

I added a new class to treat each div as a 'cell', here's the CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    display: table;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0 1em;
}

.footer-divider {
    width:0;
    padding: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid;
}
```